# Foreign logos on my site - disclaimer

Tags: copyright

on my app website are the logos of Twitter, Blogger, Facebook, Windows and others to describe the functionality of the application. 
Do I need a disclaimer that the logos are not mine or something like that?

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you use an image, icon, logo, etc. from another source, you need to follow the terms and conditions specified at the source for reuse of those assets.  For example, here is the [Guidelines for Use of the Twitter Trademark](http://support.twitter.com/articles/77641-guidelines-for-use-of-the-twitter-trademark).  Copyrights generally apply when you use the work of someone else.